# Do you need game testers? We can help

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, site-promotion

If you've got a game that's ready for testing (or will be within the next few weeks), we'd like to help you find some testers. We're going to try out our [potential Developer/Tester matchup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100819/are-you-an-android-apple-or-game-developer-looking-for-beta-testers) program in a very alpha, very version 0.1 way: matchin' people up by hand!

Basically, here's how this pilot program's going to work: if you need a beta tester for your latest project, leave an answer on this post. It should contain:

- Some information about what sort of project you're working on
- What platform it's for
- What sort of audience you're developing for
- What you look for in a tester
- How many testers you'd ideally like to work with
- Any other information you feel is relevant. (Remember, I'm no game dev! You tell me what information is useful.)

My excellent colleague [Brett](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11290/brett-white) and I will find you some testers. A handful of folks on Gaming.SE [have volunteered already](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2520/are-you-interested-in-beta-testing-games), and my hunch is that when we have specific games to ask about, we'll get many more responses.

Comment: Questions like this one (and [this one](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/479/game-development-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users)), are why we need an `announcement` tag...

Comment: This is awesome, and I might even have something ready soon-ish to be tested....

Comment: @thedaian Great! We're looking forward to testing out this idea, so please keep me posted.

Comment: I am working on my game but it will take another 1-1.5 month before its ready for beta testing! Hope this program will turn into a long term stable project. Kudos to CHAOS team! :)

Comment: Can this be used for pro development? The company I work for is always looking for one-off testers. That being said, NDA's would be required -- we can coordinate that on our side, I would think. Thoughts?

Comment: @A.A.Grapsas Personally, I don't see a problem with that usage case, but I will have to ask around. Stay tuned!

Comment: I'm surprised no one's posted yet.  I'll probably post about our game some time this week.

Comment: @Davy8, check out [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102582/were-ready-to-beta-test-our-beta-tester-matchmaking-program) for the new, sorta-official way to sign up.

Comment: @A.A.Grapsas, you are welcome to sign up as a pro developer. We will simply put you in touch with testers, like we do with all the other developers, and you can handle the rest of the details.

Comment: @Abby awesome, I've passed along the information to the correct department within our company. Thanks!

Comment: @A.A.Grapsas cool! Just keep in mind that it's a very, very, very beta-y program right now. Make sure nobody thinks they can use us as their primary method of finding testers just yet :)

Comment: @Abby no worries :)